# Need to replace number in same number in .txt file with count of numbers using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have tried using the code below, but I guess it wont work because anything between ' ' is taken as a string. Need to include this $count variable somehow. I know it is basic question, but I've just started using powershell and I can't find anything online. Thanks

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\boris.trninic\Desktop\current\AM-2794\Corr_Distribution *.aaj -recurse |
Foreach-Object {
    $count += 1
    $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
    $c = $c -replace 'Fixed_Seed=1','Fixed_Seed=$count'
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\boris.trninic\Desktop\current\AM-2794\Corr_Distribution *.aaj -recurse |
Foreach-Object {
   $count++
   $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
   $c = $c -replace "Fixed_Seed=1","Fixed_Seed=$count"
   [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am afraid that I did not formulate my question in clear way.

What I have is 5000 files all containing Fixed_Seed=1 and I need to change this so that these files have Fixed_Seed=2, Fixed_Seed=3... Fixed_Seed=5000.

That is why I included that count variable, I was supposed to get my number directly from it. But I don't know how to convert it to string and attach it to the Fixed_Seed in -replace function.